# Laravel: Getting data from a table using a foreign key

Tags: php, laravel

Im using a route to send a foreign key from a view `A` to a view `B`

```
Route::post('/ultm',  function(){
    $v = Input::get('v');
    if($v != ""){
        $movimentacoes = Movimentacoes::where('id_coop', '=' . $v)
                                        ->get();
            if(count($movimentacoes) > 0)
                return view ('movs.index')->withDetails($movimentacoes)->withQuery($v);
    }
    return view ('movs.index')->withMessage("No data found");

});
```

this is the form in view `A` that is responsible for sending the foreign key

```
    <form action="/ultm" method="POST">
        @csrf
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="v" value={{$cooperado->id}}>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                <span>Ultimas movimentações</span>
              </button>
              </span>
          </div>
      </form>
```

so i tried to show all records of that particular key on view `B`

```
@if(isset($details))
        @foreach($details as $mov)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$mov->idMov}}</td>
            <td>{{$mov->id_coop}}</td>
            <td>{{$mov->valor}}</td>
            <td>{{$mov->created_at}}</td>
            <!--<td><a href="{{ route('movs.edit',$mov->idMov)}}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a></td>
            <td>
                <form action="{{ route('movs.destroy', $mov->idMov)}}" method="post">
                  @csrf
                  @method('DELETE')
                  <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
                </form>-->
            </td>
        </tr>
  @endforeach
 @endif
```

`$mov->id_coop` is the foreign key of `$cooperado->id`, i do not know why it is not working seeing that `B` view is getting the foreign key

Comment: where did you define $details in your controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whats you should have done is:

```
Route::post('/ultm',  function(){
    $v = Input::get('v');
    if($v != ""){
        $movimentacoes = Movimentacoes::where('id_coop', '=' . $v)
                                        ->get();
            if(count($movimentacoes) > 0)
                $data['details']=$movimentacoes;
                return view ('movs.index',$data)->withDetails($movimentacoes)->withQuery($v);
    }
    return view ('movs.index')->withMessage("No data found");

});
```

Comment: my view doesn't recognize the variable $data, how can i solve this?

Comment: you dont have to pass $data to your view. what you are actually passing is $details which has already been declared on the view.

Comment: i suggest you should leave only return view ('movs.index',$data)  without ->withDetails($movimentacoes)->withQuery($v); lets see which ever one that works